# Как в javaFX запретить ввод в TextArea

Tags: java, javafx

Решил помучать *javaFX*, но столкнулся с проблемой вывода информации.
Самым оптимальным выходом я нашел использование класса *TextArea* и запрета на ввод данных в него. 
Но в сети не нашел ни одного ответа на то, как можно реализовать данную идею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как найти ответ**

Посмотрим документацию, первая ссылка по запросу ***javaFX textarea*** гуглу

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html

пункт

> Properties inherited from class javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl
> anchor, caretPosition, **[editable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#editableProperty)**, font, length, promptText, redoable,
> selectedText, selection, textFormatter, text, undoable

нажимаем на **editable** (редактируемый с англ.)

Узнаем что класс имеет поле editable, которое показывает, может ли пользователь редактировать текст.

> public final BooleanProperty editableProperty
>
> Indicates whether this TextInputControl can be edited by the user.
>
> See Also: isEditable(), **setEditable(boolean)**

А главное, находим метод **setEditable(boolean)** через который можно выставить значение для этого поля

---

**Собственно ответ:**

```
textArea.setEditable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не актуально конечно, но можно зайти в SceneBuilder и там снять галочку с пункта Editable =)